# Find all values of a, b that make the function f continuous on the whole real line

Tags: calculus, limits, continuity

> $$f(x)=\begin{cases}
> a\ln(e^2+2-x), &\text{if }x < 2\\
> x^2+bx+a, &\text{if } 2 ≤ x ≤ 3\\
> \frac{ax+b}{\pi}\arcsin\frac{1}{x-2}, &\text{if } x ≥ 3\end{cases}$$

I know I need to make the limits as x approaches 2 from the left equal the limit as x approaches 2 from the right.

I received

$$2a=4+2b+a$$
$$2b-a+4=0$$

However when I try to do the same for the limit at 3, I have arcsin there which I don't know how to work around not knowing the variables. After substituting 2b+4 for a,

$$5b+13=\frac{3b+4}{\pi}\arcsin\frac{1}{x-2}$$

Thank you so much for the help

Comment: $\lim_{x \to 3^+} \arcsin \left ( \frac{1}{x-2} \right ) = \arcsin(1/(3-2))=\arcsin(1)$=?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were on the right track.  Continuity at $x=2$ demands that

$$2a=4+2b+a\implies a-2b=4$$

Continuity at $x=3$ demands that

$$9+3b+a=\frac{3a+b}{\pi}\arcsin (1)=\frac32 a+\frac 12 b\implies a-5b=18$$

Can you solve the $2x2$ system of equations?

Comment: Thank you, I can solve it from there, but can you explain in greater detail how you simplified the expression?

EDIT

I just realized arcsin(1)\frac{\pi} is $\frac{1}{2}$

Comment: You're welcome!  My pleasure.   And certainly.  Recall that $\sin \pi/2=1$.  Thus, $\arcsin \frac{1}{3-2}=\arcsin (1)=\pi/2$.

Comment: This is perfect. Thank you!

Comment: @DanielWaleniak Well done!  You have it now.